# Apply a column containing polygon to Polygon() shapely

Tags: python, dataframe, polygon

I have a dataframe with a column called `NewPolygon` :

```
NewPolygon
[(1.23,10),(4.4, 10)...]
[(16.0,10),(8.1, 10)...]
[(2.2,10),(0, 10)...]
```

My code :

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

polygon = pd.read_csv(file_path)

point = Point(10, 1.1)

polygon = Polygon() ####How to apply the value from column `NewPolygon` here iteratively
print(polygon.contains(point))
```

How can I apply all values from `NewPolygon` to Polygon() iteratively?
`Polygon()` take a list of tuple as value such as `Polygon([(1.23,10),(4.4, 10)...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, use, [`Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html):

```
df['NewPolygon'] = df['NewPolygon'].transform(Polygon)
```

To use methods on polygon objects stored inside `NewPolygon` column, Use:

```
df['NewPolygon'].apply(lambda p : p.contains(point))
```

Comment: I figured it too : `polygon_df['NewPolygon2'] = polygon_df.apply(lambda row: Polygon(row["NewPolygon"]), axis=1)
    polygon_df['Inside_Polygon'] = polygon_df.apply(lambda row: row["NewPolygon2"].contains(point), axis=1)` Thank you!